# Outer join does not work as I want

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I have 3 tables :

- Module_Articles_Articles
- Module_Articles_Categories
- Module_Articles_Comments

and I want to display my articles in repeater with this query:

```
var context = new IPArticlesEntities();
var articles =
                (from a in context.Module_Articles_Articles
                 join c in context.Module_Articles_Categories on a.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID into joinTable1
                 from c in joinTable1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 join co in context.Module_Articles_Comments on a.ArticleID equals co.ArticleID into joinTable2
                 from co in joinTable2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 where a.IsDraft == false
                 orderby a.ArticleID descending
                 select new
                 {
                     a.ArticleID,
                     a.ArticleTitle,
                     a.ArticleContent,
                     a.Image,
                     a.Sender,
                     a.SentDate,
                     a.Summary,
                     a.Likes,
                     a.Dislikes,
                     a.Tags,
                     a.PostMode,
                     a.ViewCount,
                     c.CategoryID,
                     c.CategoryTitle,
                     AcceptedCommentsCount = 
                     (from com in context.Module_Articles_Comments where com.ArticleID == a.ArticleID && com.Status select com)
                     .Count(),
                     DeniedCommentsCount =
                     (from com in context.Module_Articles_Comments where com.ArticleID == a.ArticleID 
                          && com.Status == false select com)
                     .Count()
                 }).ToList();
            return articles;
```

It works fine when I have no data in the `Comments` table, but if I have 3 records in `comments` table it will return one record of articles 3 times!

I mean I have one article record and 3 comments for it, when I run this query it returns 3 same article records.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: That's the way `OUTER JOIN` works ... I guess your expectation is  wrong here.... if you want articles and comments, you'll get as many rows as there are comments - how else could you return all 3 comments for that article??

Comment: this is my question, if you know please help me.

Comment: As I said - that's just the way a `JOIN` works. If that's not what you expected, then you'll need to read up and learn more about how `JOIN` works in a relational database! There are tons of good tutorials out there. If you don't want the 3 rows because of the 3 comments - just don't join the `Comments` table and just retrieve the articles and show these in your repeater

Comment: You need to use GroupJoin for the purpose

Comment: yeah you're right, that was my wrong. i don't need comments here, thank you very much.

Comment: Better yet, write a proper SQL statement. If you need to do a JOIN on the web server's side, it means you have the wrong data model and treat objects as if they were tables (they aren't)

Comment: You're not using the join to Comments for anything, just remove it, and the duplicate rows will be gone - the subqueries for counting accepted/denied comments can be added just fine without a join to comments.

Comment: have you tried DISTINCT when you are selecting?